# display is not showing in text box from other class in qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have made made a DDisplay class to display my data on gui text box but I have some strange situation, when I call the function from mainwindow class it is working fine but when I try to call the same function from other class it is not working. below is the small code my program

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <ddisplay.h>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "test.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
Q_OBJECT

public:
explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
~MainWindow();
DDisplay b;
Test c;
private slots:
void display(const QString &a);

void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
QObject::connect(&b,SIGNAL(display(QString)),this,SLOT(display(QString)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::display(const QString &a){

ui->textBrowser->setText(a);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
 b.printf("hello"); //this function working fine
//c.printf("lllll"); //not working
}
```

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include <QString>
#include <ddisplay.h>
class Test
{
public:
Test();
void printf(const QString &a);
DDisplay b;
};
```

test.cpp
    #include "test.h"

```
Test::Test()
{
}
void Test::printf(const QString &a){
b.printf(a);
}
```

ddisplay.h
   #include

```
class DDisplay : public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit DDisplay(QObject *parent = 0);
void printf(const QString &a);
QString b;
signals:
void display(const QString &a);

public slots:

};
```

ddisplay.cpp
    #include "ddisplay.h"

```
DDisplay::DDisplay(QObject *parent) :
QObject(parent)
{
}

void DDisplay::printf(const QString &a)
{
b+=a;
emit display(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`c.printf("lllll"); //not working`

It's not working because you don't have a **connect** for this object. DDisplay in Test class is a dfferent instance than that in a MainWindow.

One possible solution for your question in comments below is to connect DDisplay's signal and MainWindow's slot either in main.cpp or in specialized initialization class.

Comment: so how can I get my desired result??

Comment: I just want to make a general class for display so that I can access it from any class..how can I get this?